# How to get one csv file form result of many cmdlets in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I am using 5 Get cmdlets and want to have 1 csv file. Those cmdlets are as

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * 
Get-Hotfix 
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Property * | Format-Table Name,OperatingSystem,OperatingSystemServicePack,OperatingSystemVersion -Wrap –Auto 
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product 
Get-WmiObject win32_physicalmemory | Format-Table Manufacturer,Banklabel,Configuredclockspeed,Devicelocator,Capacity,Serialnumber -autosize
```

How do I export all these in one file.
Help and Efforts are deeply appriciated

Comment: Can you include an example of what you want the csv output to be, given the cmdlet inputs you have.

Comment: I am trying to make an inventory management kind of file which could show me all users, computers in ad and also the number of software installed, os, os version, patches etc.

Comment: Looks like you got an answer below.  If the answer helped, you should click the check box to mark it as accepted.  Welcome to stack overflow ;)

Comment: Thank you .. happy to be a part of stack overflow :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to be using the `Export-Csv` cmdlet with the `-Append` and the `-Force` switches.  The `-Append` allows you to append to the CSV without overwriting it.  The `-Force` is required because the appended rows from different cmdlets will have properties that don't match.

Additionally, I changed your `Format-Table` commands to `Select-Object` commands since you're outputting the results into a CSV.  If you leave them as `Format-Table` commands you will get invalid results in your CSV.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * | Export-Csv -Path .\output.csv -Append -Force
Get-HotFix | Export-Csv -Path .\output.csv -Append -Force
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Property * | Select-Object Name,OperatingSystem,OperatingSystemServicePack,OperatingSystemVersion | Export-Csv -Path .\output.csv -Append -Force
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Export-Csv -Path .\output.csv -Append -Force
Get-WmiObject win32_physicalmemory | Select-Object Manufacturer,Banklabel,Configuredclockspeed,Devicelocator,Capacity,Serialnumber | Export-Csv -Path .\output.csv -Append -Force
```

Comment: Yes, that is absolutely correct. This did helped me thank you a lot. I was wondering if I could get a table like result. Is it possible somehow?

Comment: @Aditya Unfortunatley I don't know an easy way to do that.  You see the issue is that all those cmdlets return different fields of data, and therefore you cant easily merge them all into one cohesive table.  Rather, each one makes up a different "table" if you will.  Sorry I couldn't be of more help :(

Comment: No worries. Thank you for your support and help :)

Comment: @Aditya of course!! And if my answer helped you out, please feel free to mark it as the answer.